# Can variable names match field names?

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design

Microsoft suggested that [variable names should not match field names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182216.aspx). However I saw this extensively in Java (e.g., [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)), especially in setters and constructors. So, among these two styles:

```java
public class Class {
    private int var;

    public void set(int var) { this.var = var; }
    public int get() { return var; }
}
```

or

```java
public class Class {
    private int var;

    public void set(int varIn) { var = varIn; }
    public int get() { return var; }
}
```

1. Generally speaking, which one is preferred?
2. Does it depend on language (Java, C++, C#, etc.)?

### edit

Thanks everyone, but I don't worry much about Ruby and Objective-C where it is clear (either a coding convention or just the syntax). AFAIK, there is not a widely accepted convention on this in Java and C++ and that's why I'm concerned. (In C# we should probably just follow Microsoft without reasoning?)

Comment: I am not sure whether I should add tags of involved languages.

Comment: In Java, the answer is obviously 'yes'.  In C# given the 'should' in the wording, it is yes (though Microsoft is saying its not a good idea).  Language idioms differ by language. People's opinions on these practices will differ.

Comment: Microsoft is agnostic about how field names are capitalized/prefixed.  However, since they are saying here that variable names should not match field names, and they are specific about parameter and local variable names (which are always camelCase), I conclude that Microsoft doesn't like camelCase for field names.  The only genuine alternative is leading underscore for field names, since `m_` is horrid in so many ways.

Comment: The Microsoft/StyleCop way that I know is to always explicitly qualify member variables with "this.". If you do this (haha) it makes crispy clear code if you use the same names for (constructor) arguments and fields. Any variable not prefixed with "this." will be local. Public properties should have the same names as their member fields with the only difference that the first letter be capitalized. This all reads like breeze and the relations are always perfectly clear.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, yes, the underscore-prefix style seems to be preferred in Objective-C, and I guess I can apply the same to my Java and C++ projects. That sounds better than suffixing it with `In`.

Comment: @MartinMaat, according to the link I referred to, Microsoft seems to oppose using same name for fields and parameters even if we prefix every access to fields with `this.` because (it claims) somebody may forget to prefix, leading to potential problem.

Comment: I think today "someone might forget" is a silly argument. With tools like StyleCop you will be riminded whenever necessary.

Comment: @FranklinYu underscore prefix is probably not the best in C++ http://stackoverflow.com/a/7979846/151019 as the standard says it is reserved to the implementation

Comment: @Mark, thank you for pointing it out! You reminded me that underscore prefix does have some special meaning in some other languages (e.g., Python), so maybe it really depends on the specific language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking several different questions here.

> Can variable names match field names?

It depends on the language. In some, they can. In some, they can but one will shadow the other. In some, they can't.

> Generally speaking, which one is prefered?

It depends on the language. Or, more precisely, on the coding standards of any particular organization, which will, however, often be inspired by the community coding standard of the language (if one exists).

> Does it depends on language (Java, C++, C#, etc.)?

Yes.

In Ruby, for example, it is possible to have getters and setters look like this, and some people prefer this style:

```ruby
class Foo
  def bar
    @bar
  end

  def bar=(bar)
    @bar = bar
  end
end
```

I, and some others prefer this style:

```ruby
class Foo
  def bar
    @bar
  end

  def bar=(val)
    @bar = val
  end
end
```

Note, however, that this question will actually present itself much less often than you think, because any self-respecting Ruby programmer would not write such repetitive code by hand but instead synthesize it:

```ruby
class Class
  def generate_getter(*names)
    names.each do |name|
      define_method(name) do
        instance_variable_get(:"@#{name}")
      end
    end
  end

  def generate_setter(*names)
    names.each do |name|
      define_method(:"#{name}=") do |val|
        instance_variable_set(:"@#{name}", val)
      end
    end
  end

  def generate_getter_and_setter(*names)
    generate_getter(*names)
    generate_setter(*names)
  end
end

class Foo
  generate_getter_and_setter :bar
end
```

In fact, this pattern is *so* common, that these methods are actually shipped as part of the core library under the names of [`Module#attr_reader`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader), [`Module#attr_writer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_writer), and [`Module#attr_accessor`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor):

```ruby
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar
end
```

In Java, OTOH, it seems to be very common to actually write out each and every getter and setter in full, no matter how trivial, and *not* generate or synthesize them. So, the question presents itself much more often, and thus it is much more likely that there will be coding standards governing it. In particular, if most of your getters and setters are trivial, then the potential for confusion is rather low (how confused can you get in a method that is only a single trivial line?), and thus, it is more acceptable to use the same name for the parameter of the setter and the backing field:

```java
void setBar(X bar) { this.bar = bar; }
```

This is a pattern that is easily recognizable, and since there are so many trivial setters, programmers are drilled for this pattern, and thus can spot it even in larger, more complex, non-trivial setters.

OTOH, in C#, trivial getters and setters are usually auto-generated, so the only ones where choice of parameter name matters are the non-trivial ones, and thus the potential for confusion is greater, and the programmers aren't used to it that much:

```c-sharp
X Bar { get; set; } // auto-generated, trivial, programmer doesn't care
```

And in the case of a non-trivial setter, the language actually prescribes the name of the parameter (or, more precisely, *there is no parameter*, rather, there is a special keyword `value`, which evaluates to the value being passed to the setter), so the only choice is about how to name the backing field. For this, there are no guidelines, since the coding standards only apply to publicly visible code (i.e. `public` and `protected` members) and backing fields should be `private` (otherwise, why have getters and setters at all?). However, since fields should be named *camelCase* and properties should be named *PascalCase*, there can be no conflict between them. (This is different in a case-insensitive language like VB.NET, for example!)

```c-sharp
private X bar;

X Bar
{
    get { return bar; }
    set { bar = value; }
}
```

or

```c-sharp
private X _bar;

X Bar
{
    get { return _bar; }
    set { _bar = value; }
}
```

These two seem to be the predominant styles in the .NET community. Both of them actually violate some naming standards (*Don't name identifiers only differing in case* and *Don't use underscores*), but those standards only apply for public identifiers, which the backing field is not. Since large parts of .NET are now open source, it is actually possible to see which naming standards Microsoft itself uses internally, and they seem to favor the second one (underscore prefix). [Here is an example from the .NET Concurrent Collections, which are a rather new addition to .NET and thus should reflect fairly recent coding standards](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections.Concurrent/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/BlockingCollection.cs#L63-L70):

```c-sharp
private int _boundedCapacity;

public int BoundedCapacity
{
    get
    {
        CheckDisposed();
        return _boundedCapacity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most if not all languages allow it.

It is considered bad practice because it makes code confusing - why name two things which are different the same?

For instance if you have a radiator class with a field named temperature and you want a method that checks whether the radiator's temperature is higher than the current room temperature, which you pass in, it's better to have isWarmer(roomTemperature) than isWarmer(temperature) because you don't want this.temperature and temperature to refer to two different things when they are both relevant to the method's behavior.

With constructors or setter methods it makes sense to name them the same because the only point of the method is to assign a parameter to a field in the class.

Answer (score 0):

The standard* compilers for C++, Java, and C# all allow you to *hide* a field with a parameter or variable. In all three languages, the `this` keyword or the *class modifiers* (in case of static fields) can give you access to hidden fields. So yes, it is possible for you to have the same names for fields and variables/parameters in these languages at least in these three languages.

Some (including myself) consider field hiding a bad and dangerous practise. I have seen several subtle bugs where people end up setting/reading the wrong variable/field. These things tend to happen more with poorly tested projects or when multiple developers have worked on the same file with a considerable interval. Some projects I have worked on enforce different naming conventions for fields, parameters, and variables thus reducing the chances of accidental field hiding. There are ways to enforce this too (checkstyle/resharper).

However, some others do not consider this a bad practice. They argue that variable names should indicate what they stand for and suffixes/prefixes add to the clutter. You can make this approach work as well -provided you enforce good testing discipline and others who work on this project also find this practice comfortable to work with.

At the end of the day, the only thing that matters is the consistency of your style guidelines and the comfort level of your team in working with them. There is nothing more sinister than a guideline people hate --it will affect their productivity and may increase their motivation to bypass these practices.

`*` *For the sake of completeness I must mention that it is possible for people to tweak/modify compilers to prohibit this behaviour*.

Comment: The simple answer is that the fashion has changed.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, there is a quite strong coding convention that instance variables should start with an underscore, and matching properties (getter and setter in other languages) don't have the property. If you follow these conventions, then

```
_value = 0; // Assigns instance variable of 'self'
self.value = 0; // Calls setter method
[self setValue:0]; // Calls setter method, old-fashioned
value = 0; // Sets a local or global variable named value
```

So whatever you write, everyone sees immediately which one it is. On the other hand, if you look on stackoverflow at beginners' questions, you can bet that they don't use these coding conventions and bugs are caused by assigning to some local variable and then they can't figure out why an instance variable isn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that the fashion has changed.

I still write:

```
private int number;
//runs a method
public void Method(int number)
{
    this.number = number;
}
```

Which used to be a popular way of doing things.

Where as the new fashion is:

```
int _number;
public void RunMethod(int number)
{
    _number = number;
}
```

The second has less characters, whether it is clearer or not is subjective.

Comment: I am actually in favor of the single-character prefix since it will create fewer line-wraps (my code is no wider than 80 characters). Do you apply this to Java only, or to other language (such as C++) as well?

Comment: In the first case: If someone writes "number =" then as a language expert you know what it does, but you have no idea what the programmer intended.

Comment: The same would apply if they ommitted the underscore